# With an onchange event handler on a lightning-input-field (checkbox) in LWC can I change the required fields on/off based on the value of the checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is my current code which works when the checkbox is changed. But I need it to make the required fields required again if the checkbox is unchecked (changed again). Ideally I guess I would want to be able to check the value of the checkbox and then either require or unrequire the lightning input fields based on it's new value.

HTML:

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="Attorney_Driven_Merger_and_Acquistion__c" onchange={requiredFieldsChanged}></lightning-input-field>
```

JS:

```
requiredFieldsChanged(event){
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {           
            if(element.fieldName=='Auto_Agency__c', 'Auto_Carrier__c'){
            element.required=false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
requiredFieldsChanged(event) {
  [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')]
  .filter((element) => ['Auto_Agency__c','Auto_Carrier__c'].includes(element.fieldName))
  .forEach((element) => element.required = event.target.checked);
}
```

Where event.target.checked should be the value of the checkbox. I haven't used `lightning-input-field`, so you might need to check and see what the actual property is.

Comment: So in my case the fields start as required in the form. If the checkbox is checked I want to make them not required. Basically the checkbox being checked is the exception that the user needs to indicate so that they don't need to fill out the normally required fields. So would this be reversed in some way? I SO appreciate your assistance with this!

Comment: @JohnSchroeder yes, you could reverse it, as in: `element.required = !event.target.checked`.

Comment: Still not working. Could the problem be that the fields are starting required?

Comment: Let me clarify the above. Checking the checkbox for the onchange event handler leaves those two fields still required.

Comment: Maybe `event.target.value`? Again, I'm not terribly familiar with lightning-input-field.

Comment: event.target.value it is!

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<lightning-input-field  field-name="Attorney_Driven_Merger_and_Acquistion__c" onchange={requiredFieldsChanged}></lightning-input-field>

//required/non required based on checkbox
<lightning-input-field  field-name="field1__c" required ={required}></lightning-input-field>
<lightning-input-field  field-name="field2__c" required ={required}></lightning-input-field>


JS:
required = false;//js variable

requiredFieldsChanged(event){
    this.required = !event.detail.checked;
}
```